# How to change kivy label text in .kv dynamically from .py using Screenmanager?

Tags: python, kivy

i am very new to kivy and trying to build a multiple screen application, thus i a am using Screenmanager. The user is supposed to start at `WelcomeScreen` and shall be enabled to search for items on the `SearchScreen`. So far, so good. Unfortunately, i can not find the right way to access the MDLabels (name: 'searchResult') text property on the SearchScreen. Any ideas?

The Python File:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
import requests


class WelcomeScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class SearchScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass


class FoodApp(MDApp):

    sm = WindowManager()
    searchCache = []

    def magnify_callback(self):
        self.sm.transition.direction = "down"
        self.sm.current = "searchScreen"

    def search_something(self, text):
        results= []
        for name in self.searchCache:
            if text.lower() in name.lower():
                results.append(name)
        # Plus: Change the text of 'searchResult' MDLabel on SearchScreen, depending on search results.
        # Plus: Instantiate as many Labels as Results exist... (max. 20)



    def fetch_searchindex(self):
        try:
            request = requests.get("https://api.sampleapis.com/beers/ale")
            request = request.json()
            for obj in request:
                self.searchCache.append(obj["name"])

        except:
            pass

    def build(self):

        self.sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcomeScreen'))
        self.sm.add_widget(SearchScreen(name='searchScreen'))
        self.fetch_searchindex()

        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FoodApp().run()
```

The kivy file:

```
WindowManager:
    WelcomeScreen:
    SearchScreen:

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcomeScreen'

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: 'Welcome!'
        right_action_items: [['magnify', lambda x: app.magnify_callback()]]

<SearchScreen>:
    name: 'searchScreen'

    MDLabel:
        name: 'searchResult'
        text: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor'
        size_hint: 0.8, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.8}

    MDTextField:
        name: 'searchText'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
        size_hint: 0.8, None
        hint_text: 'Search for...'
        icon_left: 'magnify'
        on_text: app.search_something(self.text)

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'close'
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.99, 'top': 0.99}
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
            root.manager.current = 'welcomeScreen'
```

I tried to use `id` instead of `name` in the .kv File and change the MDLabel.text property via `self.sm.get_screen('searchScreen').ids.searchResult.text = 'New text'` in .py File, unfortunately i receive this error in any case...

```
[...]
File "C:\Projectpath\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Projectpath\foodapp.kv", line 27, in <module>
     on_text: app.search_something(self.text)
   File "C:\Projectpath\main.py", line 33, in search_something
     self.sm.get_screen('searchScreen').ids.searchResult.text = "Hello"
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.sm.get_screen('searchScreen').ids` is a dictionary, as can be read in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids).

And a dictionary doesn't define a `__getattr__` (attribute access) or `__setattr__` (setting attributes). Dicts in python only supports item access through `dictionary['my_key']`.
So the correct way of accessing the label would be:

```py
self.sm.get_screen('searchScreen').ids['searchResult'].text = 'New text'
```

Also note, that the `ids` dict is usually empty and only gets populated when you use ids, what isn't the case looking at your `kv` file.
(And do not put your id in quotes, as they would affect the key name to be `'searchResult'` or `"searchResult"` instead of just `searchResult` (without the quotes))